# Why is the Master Page Render event not triggered on partial postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making an ASP.NET application that performs some globalization in the Render event of the Master Page. Basically my code uses regular expressions to look for placeholders (text patterns, not actual PlaceHolder controls) in the markup and replaces them with the corresponding translations found in an XML file.

This works as intended when the page is loaded normally, but on a partial postback the Render event does not seem to trigger at all for the Master Page, leaving the rendered page full of placeholders. The event does trigger for the current Page however, but I don't want to alter the output HTML separately in every single page's Render event.

The ContentPlaceHolder (containing the current Page) of the Master Page is located inside an UpdatePanel, and I assume this has something to do with what is happening. I still don't understand why the event is not triggered, however.

Is there a way to force the Master Page Render event to trigger on partial postback, or should I consider a different solution?

Comment: It would be better if you can attach code snippets for us to better help you out.

Comment: Well I wasn't quite sure what to attach. I can't really paste the entire page here, and there isn't really anything my code is doing specifically. It's just that the Render event won't fire for the Master Page. If I disable partial rendering for my ScriptManager the event is triggered, but how can I trigger it with partial rendering enabled?